# How to vectorize double summation in matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I'm trying to produce vectorized code for this equation (and multiple others of the same form):

[image]

This will be evaluated in `ode45` and the only part that changes is `Rmn(t)` so I am pre-computing the Bessel and `sin` functions. At the moment my code looks like this:

```
for iR = 1:nR
    p(:, iR) = sum(Rmn.*J0m(:, :, iR),1)*sinanz;
end
```

`M`, `N` are the number of terms in my summation and `R`, `Z` are the number of `r` and `z` coordinates I'm using. `Rmn` is an `M*N` matrix. `J0m` is a `M*N*R` array. It is an `M*R` matrix that is repeated `N` times. `sinanz` is an `N*Z` matrix. `J0m` and `sinanz` are pre-computed and don't change.

This works but is slow and so I am trying to optimize it. I figured the first step would be to reduce `J0m` so it is only `m*R` but I can't figure out how. I am looking for any suggestions on how to do this and any suggestions on how to optimize this in general.

Comment: Have you pre-allocated `p`? That is, put a `p = zeros(Z,nR);` before the loop?

Comment: Yes I have done that. Thanks also for fixing the image and `code`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you probably already know, you should pre-allocate `p` before the loop:

```
p = zeros(Z, nR);
```

this prevents the array `p` from growing at each iteration, speeding up the loop tremendously.

You could vectorize the whole thing by virtue of [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
% C ≣ M×N×R array of all products Rmn·J0m
C = bsxfun(@times, Rmn, J0m);

% D ≣ M×N×R×Z array of all products C·sinanz
D = bsxfun(@times, C, permute(sinanz, [3 1 4 2]));

% Sum in M and N directions, and re-order
p = permute(sum(sum(D,1),2), [4 3 1 2]);
```

but I doubt it's going to be faster; MATLAB (read: BLAS) is pretty fast with 2D matrices, but usually not terribly good with more-D arrays.

I suggest you read about [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html); it's also the way to reduce the `J0m` array to `M`×`R` in the way you describe.

Of course, you can get rid of the `permute`s by properly defining your variables, so let's do a small test in the 'ideal' versions of both the looped and vectorized code:

```
%% Initialize some variables

% Number of tests
TESTS = 1e4;

% Your dimensions
M = 5;   nR = 4;
N = 2;   Z  = 3;

% Some dummy data
Rmn    = rand(M,N);
sinanz = rand(N,Z);
J0m    = rand(M,nR); % NOTE: J0m doesn't have to be 3D anymore by using bsxfun

%% Test 1: your own version, optimized

% Start test
start = tic;

% Repeat the test a couple of times to get a good average
for ii = 1:TESTS
    p1 = zeros(Z,nR);
    for iR = 1:nR
        p1(:, iR) = sum( bsxfun(@times,Rmn,J0m(:, iR)), 1 )*sinanz;
    end    
end
stop = toc(start);

% Average execution time
fprintf(1, 'Average time of looped version: %f seconds.\n', stop/TESTS);

%% Vectorized version, using 4D arrays: 

% Don't make the permutes part of the test
J0m    = permute(J0m, [1 3 2]);
sinanz = permute(sinanz, [3 1 4 2]);

% Start test
start = tic;

% Repeat the test a couple of times to get a good average
for ii = 1:TESTS
    C  = bsxfun(@times, Rmn, J0m);
    D  = bsxfun(@times, C, sinanz);
    p2 = sum(sum(D,1),2);

end
stop = toc(start);

% Average execution time
fprintf(1, 'Average time of vectorized version: %f seconds.\n', stop/TESTS);

%% Check for equality

maxDifference = max(max(p1 - squeeze(p2)'))
```

Results:

```
Average time of looped version    : 0.000054 seconds.
Average time of vectorized version: 0.000023 seconds.
maxDifference =
    4.440892098500626e-016
```

which seems pretty good! However, using

```
M = 50;   nR = 40;
N = 20;   Z  = 30;
```

you get

```
Average time of looped version    : 0.000708 seconds.
Average time of vectorized version: 0.009835 seconds.
maxDifference =
    8.526512829121202e-014
```

so the vectorized version just got *an order of magnitude* slower than the looped variant.

Of course, [your mileage may vary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary), but the take home message is that you should expect this difference to get worse and worse for increasing dimensions.

So, in conclusion:

- if your dimensions are large, stick with the loop. If they are small, also use the loop - it's just *SO* much easier on the eyes than the vectorized version :)
- make sure to pre-allocate the `p` variable
- use `bsxfun` to reduce the memory footprint (but it won't increase the speed much)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried Test 1 and it takes about twice as long to run as my original version (stays roughly the same as the dimensions change), so it looks like I have the optimal solution for now. I was aiming to run the model with M=N=50 so the second one isn't going to help either. It's good to see the alternatives though.